# lwjgl glVertex2f does not draw a square

Tags: java, lwjgl

Hey so my java pogram does not draw a square?
It can fine draw a line but when i try to draw a square it only draws half of it.

Here is what it lookes like: http://gyazo.com/1f44d59d478537199a51d3d57ccc63e4

And here is my code:

```
package data;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Boot {

    public Boot() {
        Display.setTitle("Game");
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode( new DisplayMode(600, 400));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 600, 400, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

//          glBegin(GL_LINES);
//          glVertex2f(10, 10);
//          glVertex2f(100, 100);
//          glEnd();

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glColor3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.5f);

            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2f(100, 100);
            glVertex2f(150, 100);
            glVertex2f(150, 150);
            glVertex2f(100, 150);
            glVertex2f(100, 100);
            glEnd();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }

        Display.destroy();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Boot();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `GL_LINES`, you have to explicitly specify two vertices per line segment:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 150);
glVertex2f(150, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glEnd();
```

You can also use `GL_LINE_STRIP` if you want to draw connected lines:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glEnd();
```

And in these case you can even use `GL_LINE_LOOP`, which automatically connects the last and first vertex:

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 100);
glVertex2f(150, 150);
glVertex2f(100, 150);
glEnd();
```